# Собрать рандомные значения воедино

Tags: php

Нужно собрать получившиеся значения в переменную $name

```
error_reporting(-1);

/* Слоги, из которых составляется имя */
$letters = array(
'ко',   'и',    'дзу',  'ми',
'са',   'ку',   'ра',   'да',
'чи',   'а',    'ки',   'ми',
'на',   'го',   'ха',   'ру'
);


/* Гененрируем 4 слога */
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {   
/* Выкидываем случайное число */
$random = mt_rand (0,15); 
$randomText = $letters [$random];
$letters ['name'] = $randomText;

echo "Выпало число {$random}, слог {$randomText}\n";
}

/* В эту переменную запишем получившееся имя */
$name = '';

echo "------\n";
echo "Советую имя: {$name} - не прогадаешь!\n";
```

Посоветуйте, как это сделать.

Comment: `$name = implode($letters)` так наверное

Comment: сначала надо их собрать в массив

Comment: Вы наверное для начала хотели написать `$letters['name'][$i]` ? Хотя в тот же массив неправильно было бы собирать куски..... а вообще можно прям там в цикле `name` и собирать...собссн

Comment: https://ideone.com/qNywfx

Comment: Спасибо, а почему Вы используете .= ?

Comment: Это конкатенация .....конкатинирует значение которое уже есть в текущей переменной с той, что справа от знака `=` ... в данном случае получается, что сначала добавляется значение к пустой строке, например `ра`, затем к `ра` добавляется еще слог и еще пока не закончится цикл......... по факту например `$var .= "1";` можно написать как `$var = $var."1";` ....также можно делать с арифметическими операциями .. вместо `$var = $var + 666;` писать просто `$var += 666;`

Comment: повторы слогов – ок? «Мимимими» – это в порядке вещей для самурая? )

Comment: @Sergiks `Мимимими` означает "Свободолюбивый тигрррр"

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать встроенные функции PHP, тогда составление случайного имени займёт одну строку ([рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/nwHvuI)):

```
implode(  // склеить массив в строку
  '',     // разделитель пустая строка
  array_map(  // к каждому элементу применить функцию
    function($k) use( $letters){ // дан индекс, надо слог
      return $letters[$k];       // его и возвращаем
    },
    array_rand( $letters, 4)     // получить 4 случайных индекса
  )
);
```

---

Используемые функции:

[`implode( разделитель, массив )`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) «собирает» все элементы массива в одну строку через разделитель;

[`array_map( функция, массив )`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) применит к каждому элементу массива функцию, переданную первым параметром, и вернёт новый массив, где каждый элемент - результат ф-ии;

[`array_rand( массив, сколько_индексов_надо )`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php) вернёт массив со случайными индексами данного массива – одним, или более, в этой задаче нужно 4.